Smart Contract of Solana based Token
I have created a new token using Tokencreator.io. After that, I created my openbook market id. Before I create a liquidity pool, I would like to know how can I access my smart contract?
I want to export the smart contract so I can make changes to it as well as I want to put it on GitHub.
